# post to chatter from javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

I want to post to chatter from javascript.the app I m creating is a browser extension,so its not specific to a particular domain.on clicking on a button,javascript does the oAuth dance ,and posts to chatter.is it possible,as in will it  not be affected by the same origin policy.

can you post some links,from where I can start and provide some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you writing a Chrome extension? This post may help you - for chatter you need have to reduce the api_scope as per SFDC docs...

http://www.anupshinde.com/salesforce-rest-api-chrome-extension